# Stored procedure to copy columns data to another table in Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have two table. 
Product table and Product Warehouse.

Product Table

1. Id
2. Product Name
3. Primary Warehouse
4. Secondary Warehouse
5. PrimaryWarehouseId
6. SecondaryWarehouseId

Product Warehouse Table

- Id
- Warehouse Name

Is it possible to copy Primary Warehouse and Secondary Warehouse data to Product warehouse table and update the Product table with the respective Id?

I will end with 2 rows in Warehouse table for each product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, this is one solution

```
declare @Product as table (
 [Id] int identity
,[Product Name] varchar(50)
,[Primary Warehouse] varchar(50)
,[Secondary Warehouse]varchar(50)
,[PrimaryWarehouseId] int 
,[SecondaryWarehouseId] int 
)


declare @ProductWarehouse as table(
 [Id] int identity
,[Warehouse Name] varchar(50)
)


insert @Product ([Product Name], [Primary Warehouse]  , [Secondary Warehouse]) Values ('P01', 'W1' , '101')
insert @Product ([Product Name], [Primary Warehouse]  , [Secondary Warehouse]) Values ('P02', 'W1' , '104')
insert @Product ([Product Name], [Primary Warehouse]  , [Secondary Warehouse]) Values ('P03', 'W2' , '102')
insert @Product ([Product Name], [Primary Warehouse]  , [Secondary Warehouse]) Values ('P04', 'W3' , '101')
insert @Product ([Product Name], [Primary Warehouse]  , [Secondary Warehouse]) Values ('P05', 'W4' , '103')
insert @Product ([Product Name], [Primary Warehouse]  , [Secondary Warehouse]) Values ('P06', '101' , 'W2')


insert @ProductWarehouse ([Warehouse Name] ) select distinct [Primary Warehouse] from @Product P  where not exists (SELECT 1  FROM @ProductWarehouse pw where p.[Primary Warehouse] = pw.[Warehouse Name]) 
insert @ProductWarehouse ([Warehouse Name] ) select distinct [Secondary Warehouse] from @Product P where not exists (SELECT 1  FROM @ProductWarehouse pw where p.[Secondary Warehouse] = pw.[Warehouse Name]) 


select * from @Product
select * from @ProductWarehouse 

update p
set [PrimaryWarehouseId] = pw.Id
from @Product p
inner join @ProductWarehouse pw 
on
p.[Primary Warehouse] = pw.[Warehouse Name] 

update p
set [SecondaryWarehouseId] = pw.Id
from @Product p
inner join @ProductWarehouse pw 
on
p.[Secondary Warehouse] = pw.[Warehouse Name]


select * from @Product
```

Product table

```
Id          Product Name  Primary Warehouse  Secondary Warehouse  PrimaryWarehouseId SecondaryWarehouseId
----------- ------------- ------------------ -------------------- ------------------ --------------------
1           P01           W1                 101                  NULL               NULL
2           P02           W1                 104                  NULL               NULL
3           P03           W2                 102                  NULL               NULL
4           P04           W3                 101                  NULL               NULL
5           P05           W4                 103                  NULL               NULL
```

Product Warehouse Table

```
 Id          Warehouse Name
----------- ---------------
1           101
2           W1
3           W2
4           W3
5           W4
6           102
7           103
8           104
```

Final Product table

```
Id          Product Name   Primary Warehouse   Secondary Warehouse   PrimaryWarehouseId SecondaryWarehouseId
----------- -------------- ------------------- --------------------- ------------------ --------------------
1           P01            W1                  101                   2                  1
2           P02            W1                  104                   2                  8
3           P03            W2                  102                   3                  6
4           P04            W3                  101                   4                  1
5           P05            W4                  103                   5                  7
6           P06            101                 W2                    1                  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail sample. I will try this and come back.

Comment: I created wrong table. The 'ProductId' will not be in ProductWareHouse Table. In that case how should we do?

Comment: No problem, I edited the answer to works with no ProductId in ProductWareHouse Table